# Importing BURP SUITE certificate to android emulator

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, emulation, burp

I am getting problem while intercepting HTTPS requests in Burp (intercepting tool) from android emulator ,

I am successfully able to intercept HTTP (not HTTPS) requests via BURP in android emulator ,
I saw lot of tutorials, to first grab the .cert certificate from BURP in firefox , then convert it into android supporting format and copying it to android system .

This is the exact problem I am facing :
1. I am unable to convert that SSL certificate  .
2. I tried just copying a dummy certificate just to test if copy pasting is working fine or not , I got error privileges error , I also tried 
running command  , "adb shell" and run that command adb push but still having problem to define the path of converted Certificate path , as my certificate is on main machine .

Hoping the solutions for both problems, Also it would be helpful If someone 
can give me the exact command needed to convert that SSL Certicate .

Thanks